# joining three tables in sql using union all

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, union-all

```
CREATE TABLE ZIPCODE_16P2
(
ZIPCODE NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
CITY    VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
STATE   VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ZIPCODE)
);


CREATE TABLE REGISTER_LSP_16P2
(
LAB_ID               NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
PASSWORD             VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
LAB_NAME             VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
ADDRESS              VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
ZIPCODE              NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
CONTACT_NUMBER       NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
ALTERNATE_CONTACT_NO NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
EMAIL                VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
CATEGORY             VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
SECURITY_QUESTION    VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
SECURITY_ANSWER      VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (LAB_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ZIPCODE) REFERENCES ZIPCODE_16P2 (ZIPCODE),
UNIQUE (PASSWORD),
UNIQUE (CONTACT_NUMBER),
UNIQUE (ALTERNATE_CONTACT_NO),
UNIQUE (EMAIL)
);



CREATE TABLE TBL_TEST_786
(
TEST_CODE        NUMBER (30),
LAB_ID           NUMBER (30),
TEST_NAME        VARCHAR2 (255),
TEST_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2 (255),
TEST_DURATION    NUMBER (30),
COST_OF_THE_TEST NUMBER (30),
LAB_HOME         VARCHAR2 (255)
);
```

I got three tables with me i want to join them to get required fields LAB_NAME,ADDRESS, ZIPCODE, STATE,CITY,TEST_NAME, TEST_CODE, TEST_DESCRIPTION, COST_OF_THE_TEST, LAB_HOME.
I tried joining with inner join and not getting the result can you please help me with this.

Comment: Please show us what code you have tried, some sample data and expected outcome

Comment: SELECT LAB_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIPCODE,STATE,CITY,TEST_NAME,TEST_CODE,TEST_DESCRIPTION,COST_OF_THE_TEST,LAB_HOME
FROM REGISTER_LSP_16P2,ZIPCODE_16P2,TBL_TEST_786
WHERE REGISTER_LSP_16P2.ZIPCODE=ZIPCODE_16P2.ZIPCODE AND REGISTER_LSP_16P2.LAB_ID=TBL_TEST_786.LAB_ID

Comment: that is the query i have tried and it is ORA-00918 column ambiguously defined

Comment: Update your question with the code (Use the "Edit link") and format it. It is difficult to read it in a comment and any future readers will not need to read the comments to get the additional information

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT LAB_NAME,ADDRESS,REGISTER_LSP_16P2.ZIPCODE,STATE,CITY,TEST_NAME,TEST_CODE,TEST_DESCRIPTION,COST_OF_THE_TEST,LAB_HOME FROM
 REGISTER_LSP_16P2 join ZIPCODE_16P2 on REGISTER_LSP_16P2.ZIPCODE=ZIPCODE_16P2.ZIPCODE join TBL_TEST_786 on REGISTER_LSP_16P2.LAB_ID=TBL_TEST_786.LAB_ID
```